# Как правильно сказать: соревнования, соревнования по или соревнования в?

Tags: лексика, предлоги

1. Соревнования профессионального мастерства.
2. Соревнования *по* профессиональному мастерству.
3. Соревнования *в* профессиональном мастерстве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А мне кажется, что наиболее приемлемым является третий вариант - "в мастерстве". Но иногда допустим и первый. Говорят же, например, "конкурс талантов".

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что *"профессиональное мастерство"* - это плеоназм, ибо оба они означают высокий уровень знаний и опыта в определенной теме. Так говорить не стоит.
Я бы построил высказывание так: соревнования мастеров.

Comment: Соревнования мастеров - смысл другой. Мастера соревнуются. А соревнования в мастерстве - именно соревнования на определение, мастер ли  ты.

Comment: По-моему "профессиональный" не обязательно означает высокий уровень [...]. Может быть просто "относящийся к профессии". В отличие от увлечения, хобби.

Answer (score 0):

А мне сама идея таких соревнований не нравится. Профессиональное мастерство (плеоназм оно или нет) - это не вид спорта, ***по которому*** можно проводить соревнования.
Соревнования по стрижке овец или там по поеданию блинчиков с кленовым сиропом - это понятно. А профессиональное мастерство - это грубо говоря, *уровень* овладения профессией. Не уровнями же они там мерятся?

Насколько помню, подобные соревнования обычно назывались просто профессиональными соревнованиями и конкурсами, или называлить как-то типа "Лучший по профессии".

Насчет плеоназма. От контекста зависит. В данном случае действительно смахивает на излишество. Но вообще говоря "профессионализм" шире чем профессиональное мастерство. А просто "мастество" - не всегда профессиональное. Так что если и плеаоназм, то контекстный.